# How to change a global variable inside Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to change this (defined in devise.rb):

```
@@reset_password_keys = [:email]
```

to:

```
@@reset_password_keys = [:email, :role]
```

This is eventually used (as `required_attributes`) to lookup the user in the below method which is defined in `authenticatable.rb`.

I'd like to use this to force both the `email` and `role` attributes to be sent from the reset password form.

**Usage:**

```
def find_or_initialize_with_errors(required_attributes, attributes, error=:invalid) #:nodoc:
  attributes = if attributes.respond_to? :permit!
    attributes.slice(*required_attributes).permit!.to_h.with_indifferent_access
  else
    attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(*required_attributes)
  end
  attributes.delete_if { |key, value| value.blank? }

  if attributes.size == required_attributes.size
    record = find_first_by_auth_conditions(attributes)
  end

  unless record
    record = new

    required_attributes.each do |key|
      value = attributes[key]
      record.send("#{key}=", value)
      record.errors.add(key, value.present? ? error : :blank)
    end
  end

  record
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change it in your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

`config.reset_password_keys = [:email, :role]`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/test/rails_app/config/initializers/devise.rb#L127